# Salesforce Upsert - Conserving API calls when record existence is unknown

Tags: upsert

[This is a long post since I have to explain the logic for restore. Question is in **bold**.]

I have backups of several objects (Standard and Custom) and have to perform restore. The current logic which I feel requires optimization is as follows:

1. Get the records for the object that has to be restored.
2. Identify which records have to be created or updated or undeleted by using select statements (SELECT ID FROM  WHERE ID IN (...)). This also includes object validations to check if object is createable, updateable or undeleteable.
3. Undelete records if any. If fails, mark it as to be inserted.
4. For every record that has to be created, use the create call. For every record that has to be updated, use the update call.

I have read that [upsert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_upsert.htm) is used to conserve the API calls. However, I have tried a sample upsert operation on a custom object (parent__c) which also has an external ID field (parent__c). Here are a few observations on the upsert operation:

1. Get the records that has to be restored.
2. Set all the record values.
3. Undelete records if any. If fails, mark it as to be inserted.
4. Perform upsert on the lookup field.

Step 4 is quite ambiguous since there are varying results when performed upsert on ID vs external Id field parent__c. There are two records on my backup with the Id 'a0Q36000008PyZ4EAK' (present in salesforce) and 'a0Q36000008PyZ4EAL' (absent in salesforce).

- When performed upsert on ID, record which is present is updated. If the record is not present it throws, MALFORMED_ID,
  malformed ID a0Q36000008PyZ4EAL.
- When performed upsert on external ID field parent__c, record which is
  present is updated. If record is not present, the record is created.

**Why is there a difference in behaviour on the upsert call on System ID field vs external Id field?**

I might be overthinking this process if this can be performed only on external ID field. Here it goes:

1. Get the records that has to be restored.
2. Set all the record values.
3. Undelete records if any. If fails, mark it as to be inserted. **In order to find the records that are present in the recycle bin, check if record has isDeleted = 'true'. This is exactly the anti-thesis of determining whether it is present or not and using upsert. How can this be avoided?**
4. Add an external ID field to the object to be restored. Added a text field. **Is there a way to default the formula to the Id field? If not, what should be performed here? Probably another API call such as update/insert which actually destroys the optimization of using upsert. If update is performed, update for records which are not present will be thrown with errors. Is this fine?**

Here is the sample code that is used for upsert:

```
private void upsert() throws ConnectionException
    {
        PartnerConnection soapConnection = ConnectionManager.getSoapConnection();
        String parentName = "parent__c";
        String extField = "parent__c";
        List<SObject> records = new ArrayList<>();

        // Parent record
        SObject parentRec = new SObject();
        parentRec.setType(parentName);
        parentRec.setId("a0Q36000008PyZ4EAK");
        parentRec.setField("name", "testname");
        parentRec.setField(extField, "a0Q36000008Pxz6EAD");
        records.add(parentRec);

        logger.info("Begin");
        UpsertResult[] results = soapConnection.upsert("Id", records.toArray(new SObject[records.size()]));
        for (UpsertResult result : results)
        {
            if (!result.getSuccess())
            {
                StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder();
                for (com.sforce.soap.partner.Error error : result.getErrors())
                    errors.append(error.getStatusCode() + " " + error.getMessage()).append("; ");
                logger.info("Error Message: {}", errors.toString());
            }
            else if (result.isCreated())
            {
                logger.info("Created with record id {}", result.getId());
            }
            else
            {
                logger.info("Updated the record");
            }
        }
        logger.info("Done");
    }
```

Comment: Maybe a dedicated Apex API would be an easier way to keep the API call count down. Pass in a batch of records and let the backing Apex sort out the required action.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by `dedicated Apex API`. Currently using SOAP/Bulk API using Java. My question(s) are that 1) upsert does not handle if ids are present in recycle bin (which means to individually query the records in recycle bin). 2) upsert on system id is not possible? If not, 3) this requires creating a new field and populating them with the existing id. I was not able to find a way to pre-populate and therefore have to resort to update calls. If 2) is not possible, all the intermediate steps required to create field results in excessive api calls than the actual method.

Comment: I was thinking of creating an Apex method using the [webservice keyword](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_web_services_methods.htm) that performed the required logic. This would reduce the number of API calls required. However, you would still need to do the additional steps of checking the recycle bin for a record that potentially needs to be undeleted.